# Не отображаются данные ajax на странице хотя данные приходят на Network XHR

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="1.jpg">
</head>

<body>
<script>
$('document').ready(function(){
    $("#r3").click(function(){
   $.ajax ( {
                   url: "index.php",
                   type: "GET",
                   data: ({name: "admin", number: '5'}),
                   dataType: 'text',
                   success: function(){ alert('jjfj')}

               });
    });
});
</script>
<button id="r3">отправить</button>
<?php echo $_GET['name'];  ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: я подключил библиотеку jQuery и решил отправить c помощью ajax ,данные методом GET на php файл ,данные приходят на страницу это видно когда просматриваешь через браузер на Network ,а когда я хоть как-нибудь пытаюсь вывести то их как будто нет, хотя они приходят. Я хочу чтобы они хотя бы просто отображались,а то они пока это не делают.

Comment: какие данные вам приходят в network?

Comment: Мне приходят  comments.php name=Admin&number=5 GET

Comment: alert работает?

Comment: Да все функции Jquery работают кроме ajax

Comment: Да все функции Jquery работают кроме ajax

Comment: `success: function(){ alert('jjfj')}` здесь alert скабатывает?? покажите php код

Comment: Success alert работает

Comment: Весь php код я вставил

Answer (score 0):

короч не знаю правильно это или нет но ajax заработал 
        success: function(data) {

```
    console.log(data); // Возвращаемые данные выводим в консоль
    $('html').html(data);
   }
```

самое главное это 
$('html').html(data);